# How to get an array of highlighted rows in a table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, row, css-tables

I have a table and when the user clicks on a row it's highlighted yellow.  I use a class to set the color using CSS, as in:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

Now, when the user clicks a submit button, I want to get all the highlighted rows, then get a specific column value from that row, and then put them into an array.  I'm missing something though as my selector isn't putting any row data in the array.

```
var arr = $('#tbl tr').filter(":has(.highlight)");
```

This is what I used in another function to get the value from a single row when the user clicked on it.  The code below works, but I need to do this for all the highlighted rows.

```
$(this).find('#selectedRowItem').text()
```

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4. by the way.

Also, I was looking into using the data function to cache it as a better alternative, but opted for an array as a easier solution.

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: Try `$("#tbl .highlight")` If you post more code or put an example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), I can show you full correct way using your code

Comment: do you have non-unique ID's in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $highlighted = $('#tbl tr.highlight');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var highlighted=$('body .highlight');
```

This will do, then you can usea **$.each** to loop through the array

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $highlighted = $("#tbl .highlight [id=selectedRowItem]");
var arr = $.map( $highlighted, function (el, i) {
    return $highlighted.eq(i).text();
});
```

However, I strongly suggest you change the selectedRowItem ID to a classname, ID's must be unique.

Comment: It is. I'm defining it dynamically with a struts2 tag, as in: <td id="selectedRowItem" ... and it's wrapped in a <s:iterator ... tag that puts a new item for each row that is generated.

Comment: Right, but that means you have that table cell with the same `id="selectedRowItem"` for each row, correct?

Comment: Correct. My mistake, I forgot that the tags are just spitting out plain html and aren't doing anything else with it. I can use the classname or at a counter to the id as the value, I've done that before.

Comment: The classname would be the easiest as then you wouldn't have to keep up with the counter.

Comment: Agreed.  I think I'll do that. BTW, the code above has a syntax error according to my firebug console.

Comment: Np. I figured that, so I gave you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

James, you don't need to puts 'has' in your selector. So, using the code below, your selector will works

```
$('#tbl tr').filter(".highlight")
```

Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/estevao_lucas/kDSmS/. I hope this help you.